# r requests. downloading data from multiple url

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, download

I have a code that works. I can get it to save it to a csv.  Now I want to save multiple csv from multiple lists
e.g. url one: Chelsea.csv, url two: Manchester United.csv, etc

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs



headers = ['Competition', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Date Keep',
           'Total Score (Home + Away Score)', 'Goal Difference (Home - Away Score)']
r = requests.get('https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=536&comp_id=1&teamTabs=results')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

h_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')]
a_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]
total_scores = [h + a for h, a in zip(h_scores, a_scores)]
diff_scores = [h - a for h, a in zip(h_scores, a_scores)]
limit = len(a_scores)
comps = [i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a', limit=limit)]
dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide', limit=limit)]
h_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a', limit=limit)]
a_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a', limit=limit)]


df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(comps, h_teams, h_scores, a_teams, a_scores, dates, total_scores, diff_scores)),
                  columns=headers)

df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Can I please get help in building the url.txt, calling it in this function/code and saving it as per preferably another reference list eg value (the value that changes in the url and name it as Chelsea).
This community is so awesome. I have got this far.. Thank you @Qharr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to grab the links of the individual teams, put that into a list/dictionary, then iterate through that. So something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

url = 'https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/home.sd'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

teams = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("/teams/team.sd?"))  #<---- made change here

teams_dict = {}
for team in teams:
    link = 'https://www.soccerbase.com' + team['href']
    team = team.text

    teams_dict[team] = link

for k, v in teams_dict.items():
    print ('Aquiring %s data...' %(k))

    headers = ['Competition', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Date Keep',
               'Total Score (Home + Away Score)', 'Goal Difference (Home - Away Score)']
    r = requests.get('%s&teamTabs=results' %(v))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    h_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')]
    a_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]
    total_scores = [h + a for h, a in zip(h_scores, a_scores)]
    diff_scores = [h - a for h, a in zip(h_scores, a_scores)]
    limit = len(a_scores)
    comps = [i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a', limit=limit)]
    dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide', limit=limit)]
    h_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a', limit=limit)]
    a_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a', limit=limit)]


    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(comps, h_teams, h_scores, a_teams, a_scores, dates, total_scores, diff_scores)),
                      columns=headers)

    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\%s.csv' %(k), sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi @chitown88, Can you give me an example of what would be the contents of the .txt file? Would it contain the list of URLs directly? Where would the location of the .txt file be?

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!
One question however, This code just downloads all premier league teams data. However, I am looking accross all teams in the football universe as on this website. What is the differentiator for the same? Where do I put my list in? What would be the format of the code? Many Thanks!

Comment: Would the list of the teams be team names?

Comment: Hi @chitown88, how can I do the same for non-premier league teams?

Comment: can you please guide me?

Comment: hey. It's not a .txt file. What `.text` is doing is pulling the text/contnet on the html element (so that it can be used as a way to save the filename associated). To do the other leagues, you'll have to go tho that url and iterate through that to get those teams.

Comment: @PYNoob, actually just needed to make a slight change to the code. It should grab all the teams now